# Can anyone figure out this code for me?

Tags: python

```
import random

print "Welcome to the number guesser program. We will pick a number between 1 and 100 and then ask you to pick a number between 1 and 100. If your number is 10 integers away from the number, you win!"

rand_num = random.randint(1, 100)


user_input = raw_input('Put in your guess:').isdigit()
number = int(user_input)

print number

if abs(rand_num - number) <= 10:
    print "Winner"
else:
    print "Loser"
```

Whenever I try to run this code, the computer always generates the number 1. And if I put in a number that is 10 (or less) integers away from one it will still display the else statement. I will have my gratitude to whoever can solve my predicament. I am new to python try to keep your answers simple please.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` returns a string you entered as input. `isdigit()` checks whether a string is a digit or not and returns True or False.

In your code you're assigning *the return value of `isdigit`* to `user_input`  So, you get either `True` or `False`. Then you convert it to a number, thus getting either one or zero. This is not what you want.

Let `user_input` be just a result of `raw_input`. Then check whether it is a valid number with `user_input.isdigit()`. If it's not a number, print an error message and exit (or re-ask for input), else convert `user_input` to an integer and go on.

Comment: IMHO, `try: int(raw_input("...")); except: error message` would be better than `if-else`

Comment: @Lafexlos, agreed. It seems that the OP wants to use `isdigit` very much, but having problems with it, so I showed how to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is product by this sentenc:

```
user_input = raw_input('Put in your guess:').isdigit().
```

The return value of isdigit() is True or False. When you enter 1 or any digit number, it will return True(True=1,False=0), so you will always get 1, if you enter digit. You can change like this:

```
    import random

    print "Welcome to the number guesser program. 
    We will pick a number between      
    1 and 100 and then ask you to pick a number 
    between 1 and 100. If your number is 10 integers
    away from the number, you win!"

    rand_num = random.randint(1, 100)

    user_input= raw_input('Put in your guess:')
    is_digit = user_input.isdigit()
    if is_digit==True:
        number = int(user_input)
        print number
        if abs(rand_num - number) <= 10:
            print "Winner"
        else:
            print "Loser"
    else:
        print 'Your input is not a digit.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:
`user_input = raw_input('Put in your guess:').isdigit()`

The function `raw_input` gives you user input, but then you call `isdigit` and as consequence in your variable `user_input` you get result of `isdigit`. So, it has boolean value.

Then in 
`number = int(user_input)`  you cast it to integer type. In python true is 1 and false is 0. That's why you always get 1.